# android-maven-plugin 3.8.2 not covered by lifecycle

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2e, android-maven-plugin, m2e-wtp

On Eclipse 4.3.2 my POM was using `com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.5.1` with no problems. I tried to upgrade it to 3.8.2 (the latest), and I got the dreaded "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error.

So of course I tried to do a "Quick Fix" of "Discover new m2e connectors". But the m2e Marketplace says "No marketplace items are available". What do I do?

*Other Information*

I have m2e-wtp - Maven Integration for WTP 1.0.1.20130911-1545 org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.feature.feature.group installed. When I tried to install "Maven Integration for Eclipse (Juno and newer) 1.4" from the marketplace, it told me there was nothing to update. When I tried to install "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno) 1.0.1" from the marketplace, I'm told:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033)
Missing requirement: Maven JPA Configurator 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.jpt.jpa.core [3.0.0,3.3.0)' but it could not be found
Cannot satisfy dependency:
  From: m2e-wtp - JPA configurator for WTP (Optional) 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033 (org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033)
  To: org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.jpa [1.0.1.e42-20130821-1033]
```

(sigh) This dependency stuff is out of control... I'm completely lost.

Comment: Maven is a real pain in my a**

Answer (score 1):

I note in the [maven-android-plugin changelog](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/Changelog) that version 3.8.2 requires Maven 3.1.1+. I'm using Maven 3.0.5 (which is required by another client). I also note that the changelog mentions that the upcoming version 3.9.0 will "[change] from direct Aether usage to Dependency Tree usage allowing compatibility with Maven 3.0.x and therefore with IDE's and other tools that have old Maven version like this embedded".

So I switched to maven-android-plugin 3.7.0, the last version that indicated Maven 3.0.x support, and the connector error went away.

*Update:* As of 2014-06-01, version 3.9.0-rc.2 of the plugin works with Maven 3.0.5, so I assume the final release will as well.

*Update 2014-06-08:* Today I updated to Eclipse 4.4RC4, and I'm getting the "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration" error all over again.